# How to Route Network Traffic on Android

Tags: android, networking, routes, android-source, android-9.0-pie

I am trying to modify the routing table such that I will be able to route the traffic on a custom interface. Is there any way to modify the Android Routing Table on Andorid 9.0 (PIE) ?

I have tried using the IP command in my native code (From Vendor ) which is

> system("/system/bin/ip -6 route add fe80::/64 dev custom0");
>
> system("/system/bin/ip -6 rule add from all lookup main pref 1");

As Android 9 is treble compliant I get an error with SELinux issues regarding vendor_shell_exec is never allow. Hence I will not be able to modify the routing table.

Is there any way to modify the routing table while being Treble Compliant, Is there any JAVA method which helps me to get my desired output ?